# How to redirect on error with Everyauth / Node.js

Tags: javascript, authentication, node.js

When trying to authenticate with a wrong user/pass combination, [everyauth](https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth) always throws an error at every module.js:352

```
./node_modules/everyauth/lib/modules/everymodule.js:352
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Name or password is incorrect.
    at gen_err (./node_modules/nano/error.js:93:43)
    at Object.couch (./node_modules/nano/error.js:102:48)
    at Request.callback (./node_modules/nano/nano.js:147:26)
    at Request.<anonymous> (./node_modules/nano/node_modules/request/main.js:314:21)
    at Request.emit (events.js:64:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (./node_modules/nano/node_modules/request/main.js:295:19)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:81:20)
    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:133:23)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1231:22)
    at Socket._onReadable (net.js:677:27)
```

This is my authentication code:

```
.authenticate( function (login, password) {
    var promise = this.Promise();
  var auth = nano.auth(login, password, function(error, document, headers) {
    if (error) {
        return promise.fail(error);
    } else if (document.userCtx.name === login && document.ok === true) {
      console.log(login);
      var user = nano.user(login, function(error, document, headers) {
        console.log(document);
        return promise.fulfill(document);
      });
    }
  });
  return promise;
})
```

Works fine with correct user/pass and forwards to 'loginSuccessRedirect'. But with the error thrown the Node server always hangs up and crashes, instead of redirecting to 404 or 401.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Having the same problem, as soon as the promise fails, an exception is thrown and node shuts down

Comment: No, I went with promise.fulfill instead.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to go with that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return promise.fail(error);` is wrong.

The API states that one should fulfill the promise with an `Array` of errors so

`promise.fulfill([error])`

would work

Comment: There are examples in the README which use .fail() and it's in the Promise library as well. And it works, just the redirect doesn't. Kind of conflictive to fulfill something with an error, no?